# Running out of RAM without having any program to blame

Tags: windows-7, windows, memory

Sine some weeks I'm regularly running out of RAM. I'm using Win 7 64 bit with 8 GB of RAM
I am not running a huge amount of programs only skype, spotify and chrome but my RAm usage is always at around 80% wich was different some months ago.

Windows constantly tells me it has to close skype or some other program because it's running out of RAM.

The problem is it is not one particular program that is using up the RAM neither it's the combination of them. When I sum up the memory usage of all tasks I end up with about 1.2 GB.
I tried closing all programs and RAM usage was still at ~55% (>5GB)

I have tried running some anti Virus software but it didn't help.

Is there any way I can find out why RAM usage is so high and how can I change this. I know it all used to work before and for some reason windows is just wasting ram for no real reason.

- Chrisian

Comment: post pictures of RAMMAP: http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/ff700229.aspx

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Chrome is a memory hungry program. The more tabs you have open, the more ram it will consume.

That said, with 8 GB of ram, you definitely should not get memory messages.

This means one of the following things may be going wrong.

## Swapfile issue

Windows creates a swapfile to store swap memory in. This file, by default, is located on your C drive, root. If there is little space left, (less than 2 gb) the swapfile is not getting big enough and windows may give this error. So check where the swapfile is located and if there's sufficient space left.

## Memory gone bad

It may be that one of your RAM banks has gone bad. You can do an extensive memory test to make sure they're working correctly.

## Something in windows gone wrong

And in case that doesn't do it either, I've seen something in windows gone bad (was unable to find any cause, but this error would pop up with not any program open either, no virusses or spyware or anything on the machine, no processes open) and a windows reinstall fixed it. You could attempt to do that if all else fails.

Comment: Thaks for the quick reply.
The swapfile (virtrual RAM) is et to 400-2048MB on my Main SSD wich has >40GB of free space

I did a memory check (the windows RAM test tool) 2 days ago and everything was fine.

Guess I'll need to reinstall windows soon - meh

Comment: Try increasing the swapfile first. I have 12 GB of system ram, and my swapfile is also 12 GB. For windows 7 it is recommended to let windows manage the swapfile, but I would recommend placing it on a non SSD drive if possible so you can allow it to grow as needed without risking having your SSD run below 25% free space of total capacity, which will seriously slow down your SSD.

Comment: Problem probably solved had to reinstall Windows for another reason. Thanks though.